# Installing quickfix problem for python in windows 10 environment

Tags: installation, quickfix

I  am trying to get quickfix to install as a python module.  The repository at UC Irvine seem no longer to be viable.  I am, unfortunately, not expert in python.  I have tried several methods, but all fail.  I will include the messages below.

Note:  I have set up an environment using conda
python 3.7.10

Note that in many of the posts, there is reference to a repository at UC Irvine to different install versions.  This repository apparently is no longer available, so perhaps simply finding the different install versions would be a good place to start, but I cannot find them.
I also wnet through a length vcpkg installation, but the python environment does not see it.
Thanks for any help!

I tried the following:
pip install quickfix==1.15.1
the following message occurs:

```
pip install quickfix==1.15.1
Collecting quickfix==1.15.1
  Using cached quickfix-1.15.1.tar.gz (1.5 MB)
  Preparing metadata (setup.py) ... done
Building wheels for collected packages: quickfix
  Building wheel for quickfix (setup.py) ... error
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error

  python setup.py bdist_wheel did not run successfully.
  exit code: 1

  [14 lines of output]
  Testing for std::tr1::shared_ptr...
  test_std_tr1_shared_ptr.cpp
  test_std_tr1_shared_ptr.cpp(1): fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'tr1/memory': No such file or directory
  ...not found
  Testing for std::shared_ptr...
  cl : Command line warning D9002 : ignoring unknown option '-std=c++0x'
  test_std_shared_ptr.cpp
  ...found
  Testing for std::unique_ptr...
  cl : Command line warning D9002 : ignoring unknown option '-std=c++0x'
  test_std_unique_ptr.cpp
  ...found
  cl : Command line error D8021 : invalid numeric argument '/Wno-deprecated'
  error: command 'C:\\Program Files\\Microsoft Visual Studio\\2022\\Professional\\VC\\Tools\\MSVC\\14.37.32822\\bin\\HostX86\\x64\\cl.exe' failed with exit code 2
  [end of output]

  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
  ERROR: Failed building wheel for quickfix
  Running setup.py clean for quickfix
Failed to build quickfix
Installing collected packages: quickfix
  Running setup.py install for quickfix ... error
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error

  Running setup.py install for quickfix did not run successfully.
  exit code: 1

  [16 lines of output]
  C:\Users\monty.WOOD-ANALYTICS\.conda\envs\Trade0\lib\site-packages\setuptools\command\install.py:37: SetuptoolsDeprecationWarning: setup.py install is deprecated. Use build and pip and other standards-based tools.
    setuptools.SetuptoolsDeprecationWarning,
  Testing for std::tr1::shared_ptr...
  test_std_tr1_shared_ptr.cpp
  test_std_tr1_shared_ptr.cpp(1): fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'tr1/memory': No such file or directory
   ...not found
  Testing for std::shared_ptr...
  cl : Command line warning D9002 : ignoring unknown option '-std=c++0x'
  test_std_shared_ptr.cpp
  ..found
  Testing for std::unique_ptr...
  cl : Command line warning D9002 : ignoring unknown option '-std=c++0x'
  test_std_unique_ptr.cpp
  ...found
  cl : Command line error D8021 : invalid numeric argument '/Wno-deprecated'
  error: command 'C:\\Program Files\\Microsoft Visual Studio\\2022\\Professional\\VC\\Tools\\MSVC\\14.37.32822\\bin\\HostX86\\x64\\cl.exe' failed with exit code 2
  [end of output]

  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
error: legacy-install-failure

Encountered error while trying to install package.

quickfix

note: This is an issue with the package mentioned above, not pip.
hint: See above for output from the failure.
```

Answer (score 0):

The fix to this problem was actually very simple.  I had set up a separate environment with Python 3.7 in which to install quickfix.  The problem was that, when I activated that environment in the usual way, it actually was NOT the active environment.  I activated and double checked that it was the active environment, and then everything installed just fine.